# Using azcopy login --identity from within a function app in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-managed-identity, azcopy

I am trying to use `azcopy login --identity` from within a function app to authenticate with the system-assigned managed identity for the function app. I understand that azcopy login --identity is desgined to be used with virtual machines rather than apps, but I was hoping there was a way to bypass this.
Currently, we're just getting a timeout error.
An explanation of how `azcopy login --identity` works under the hood (e.g. are there some env variables we can mock up?) would be useful, or any ideas on how to set this up would be great.
We are running on a Linux-based app service

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it would work within a function app unless the function app can talk to Azure instance metadata service.

> harsha@MUCL104558:~$ azcopy login --identity
>
> Failed to perform login command: please check whether MSI is enabled
> on this PC, to enable MSI please refer to
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/qs-configure-portal-windows-vm#enable-system-assigned-identity-on-an-existing-vm:
> Get
> "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fstorage.azure.com":
> dial tcp 169.254.169.254:80: connect: connection refused

From above command, you can see a GET call is being made to `169.254.169.254` which hosts metadata API used during provisioning of VMs on cloud.

Comment: My thinking of why we may be able to work around this though - during actual function runtime, we can call DefaultAzureCredential() which will generate a MI token. So at function runtime, looks like we can generate the token fine. Unfortunately, azcopy doesn't seem to be able to do so.

Comment: Hmm., I've never used functions. But, I see the identity is mostly tied up with `vms` having taken a look at code [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/blob/93270d0e8bf9d02c62aec49228762bbf90813fd2/cmd/helpMessages.go#L276-L294). I see env vars being supported but that's for managed identity ids, but not to override [MSIEndpointAzureVM ](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/blob/058bd5bc5b970074520e4ee088b15328d888c483/common/oauthTokenManager.go#L60)

Comment: Comments [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/blob/058bd5bc5b970074520e4ee088b15328d888c483/common/oauthTokenManager.go#L772-L776) won't mention any env var..